# how to resolve Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest in dhtmlxTree

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on dhtmlxTree and angular js, tree is successfully loaded but its having error

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog]     http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest


 ...f e?JSON.stringify(e):e;d+=c(e)}return Error(d)}}function ta(a)  {if(null==a||Va(a...
```

my code is

```
 tree = new dhtmlXTreeObject("treeboxbox_tree", "100%", "100%", 0);
        tree.setImagePath("dhx/imgs/dhxtree_skyblue/");
        tree.openItem(10);
        tree.attachEvent("onClick", function (iid)
        {
            $scope.taxType.id = iid;
        }
 var testArray = TaxesService.getTreeData(taxType);
        testArray.then(function (response) {
            $scope.testArr = response.data;
            alert("-->" + $scope.testArr.treeData);


            tree.loadJSArray(eval($scope.testArr.treeData));
            tree.enableHighlighting(true);
}
```

how to solve this error,
any help will be appreciated, 
thanks in advance

Comment: code sample or more details would be helpful here

Comment: yes I have added code